# Displaying the mysql result in different format using php

Tags: php

I am getting price values from mysql database table  with the given php code

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT (price) FROM  'table' order by price asc";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $price=number_format($row[price]);
}
$price=implode(',',$price);
```

The result is `2,299,4,600,5,800,8,000,12,700,16,900,23,978,27,098`

but i want to display the result as 
 `$2,500 or less,$5,000 or less,$7,500 or less,$10,000 or less,$15,00 or less,$20,000 or less,$25,000 or less,$30,000 or less`

Can anyone tell me how o fix this problem

Comment: Can you provide some code how you are getting the values.?

Comment: You do this by writing code that does it. Have you tried that?

Comment: I am getting values form the mysql database table @User016

Comment: I asked you for the code..Not how.

Comment: You do realize that you've made a typo in `$sql="SELECT DISTINCT (price) FROM  'table' order by price asc"` ? Missing semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$price = '$' . number_format(ceil($row['price']/2500.0)*2500) . ' or less';
```

The [ceil](http://php.net/ceil) function takes a floating-point number and returns the next-highest integer. By dividing by `2500.0` and then multiplying again, we get the next-highest multiple of 2500.

Comment: Thanks, i am getting correct result, can u tell me how to get the remove duplicate values from the resultant output..
Getting output as
$7,500 or less,$10,000 or less,$10,000 or less,$12,500 or less,$12,500 or less,$15,000 or less,$15,000 or less,$15,000 or less

Comment: http://php.net/array_unique